# How to add li element with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild, createelement, setattribute

I'm trying to add this code to my page:

```
<li><a href="#" target="_blank" id="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
```

Here is the full list:

```
<ul class="social" id="social">
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank" id="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank" id="pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank" id="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the script I wrote:

```
//Add Twitter
var newLi = document.createElement('li');
var newA = document.createElement('a');
var newI = document.createElement('i');

newA.setAttribute('id', 'twitter');
newA.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
newI.setAttribute('class', 'fa');
newI.setAttribute('class', 'fa-twitter');
newI.setAttribute('class', 'fa-2x');

newLi.appendChild(newA);
newA.appendChild(newI);

var position = document.getElementById('social');

position.appendChild(newLi);
```

Comment: Works for me...(beside the href attribute and at least an image or text...) what's the issue on your-end?

Comment: It's much easier to set properties than to use setAttribute, e.g. `newA.id = 'twitter';`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the href value for your anchor and there's no content within the actual link so nothing shows.

```
newA.setAttribute('href', '#');
newA.innerHTML = 'something';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d9vj2xwt/

You also should try using element.classList.add() to add the classes, so you're not overwriting

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever thought of using JQuery?

The script would be as easy as this:

```
<script>
$('#social').append('<li><a href="#" target="_blank" id="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by a few others you are overriding the class, not appending a new class.

The old way of adding the classes would be to sepearte the classes with a whitespace

```
newI.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-twitter fa-2x');
```

But with most modern browsers you can use [classList.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)

```
newI.classList.add('fa');
newI.classList.add('fa-twitter');
newI.classList.add('fa-2x');
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3rgdvq70/

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I see my current issues, but I still must be doing something wrong (I'm new to this). Here is what I've got now:

    //Add Twitter
var newLi = document.createElement('li');
var newA = document.createElement('a');
var newI = document.createElement('i');

newA.setAttribute('id', 'twitter');
newA.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
newI.classList.add('fa');
newI.classList.add('fa-twitter');
newI.classList.add('fa-2x');


newLi.appendChild(newA);
newA.appendChild(newI);

var position = document.getElementById('social');

position.appendChild(newLi);

Comment: @LanceBeaudry—don't add that as a comment, add it as an edit to the OP. YOu have "newLI" and then "newLi".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `newI.setAttribute('class',` it is overwriting the previously added class. You will notice the same thing when you do `console.log(newI)`.

So, set all the classes for it in one go, like this:

```
newI.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-twitter fa-2x');
```

Here is the **working code snippet**:

```js
var newLi = document.createElement('li');
var newA = document.createElement('a');
var newI = document.createElement('i');

newA.setAttribute('id', 'twitter');
newA.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
newI.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-twitter fa-2x'); // set all classes in one go!

newLi.appendChild(newA);

console.log(newLi);  // check it here

newA.appendChild(newI);

var position = document.getElementById('social');

position.appendChild(newLi);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<ul class="social" id="social">
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" id="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" id="pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" id="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:** Also add the `href` attribute as pointed by @Kierkegaurd

**EDIT2:** If you mean to refer the code that you posted as a comment to @epascarello's answer, here is my take:

Your code looks correct to me, its just that you havent set the `href` attribute for `newA`.

Here is the **updated working code snippet:**

```js
//Add Twitter 
var newLi = document.createElement('li'); 
var newA = document.createElement('a'); 
var newI = document.createElement('i'); 

newA.setAttribute('id', 'twitter'); 
newA.setAttribute('target', '_blank'); 

newA.setAttribute('href', '#'); // set href here

newI.classList.add('fa'); 
newI.classList.add('fa-twitter'); 
newI.classList.add('fa-2x'); 

newLi.appendChild(newA); 
newA.appendChild(newI); 

var position = document.getElementById('social');

position.appendChild(newLi);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<ul class="social" id="social">
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" id="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" id="pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" id="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Here's what I've got and still can't seem to get it.

Comment: @LanceBeaudry Please refer to **EDIT2** in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Why mess with DOM nodes at all?

```
var wantToAdd = "<li><a href='#' target='_blank' id='twitter'><i class='fa fa-twitter fa-2x'></i></a></li>";
document.getElementById("social").innerHTML += wantToAdd;
```

Comment: That will remove all the other LIs, not sure the OP wants to do that.

Comment: Do not promote the anti-pattern of treating the DOM as a string.

Comment: @torazaburo—you should explain why you consider that an anti–pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can make life easier using innerHTML:

```
var newLi = document.createElement('li');
newLi.innerHTML = '<a id="twitter" target="_blank" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"><i></i></a>';
var position = document.getElementById('social');
position.appendChild(newLi);
```

Comment: Love down voters who are too lazy to explain their vote.